# Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched

Tags: android-emulator

I tried working the Hello World application and the emulator freezes after it flashes the Android start screen. The home page is not shown. The last display on the console is

> Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...

I tried reinstalling Eclipse and Android again. It still did not work. Also the console does not show any errors. The log cat has the following errors:

> 06-18 20:39:11.543: ERROR/flash_image(544): can't find recovery partition
>   06-18 20:39:11.843: ERROR/vold(538): Error opening switch name path '/sys/class/switch/test2' (No such file or directory)
>   06-18 20:39:11.843: ERROR/vold(538): Error bootstrapping switch '/sys/class/switch/test2' (m)
>   06-18 20:39:11.843: ERROR/vold(538): Error opening switch name path '/sys/class/switch/test' (No such file or directory)
>   06-18 20:39:11.843: ERROR/vold(538): Error bootstrapping switch '/sys/class/switch/test' (m)
>   06-18 20:46:31.842: ERROR/MemoryHeapBase(578): error opening /dev/pmem: No such file or directory
>   06-18 20:46:31.892: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(578): Couldn't open /sys/power/wait_for_fb_sleep or /sys/power/wait_for_fb_wake
>   06-18 20:46:32.313: ERROR/GLLogger(578): couldn't load  library (Cannot find library)
>   06-18 20:46:33.634: ERROR/GLLogger(578): couldn't load  library (Cannot find library)

Answer (score 107):

The solution which worked for me is, when you get the message:

> Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...

Wait for few seconds and then right click on the project and click run as Android application once again.

Comment: For those of you that this worked for, did it launch a new emulator or was it bound to your existing emulator correctly?

Comment: @Gibron: It bounds to existing emualtor, doesn't open new emulator.

Comment: I then installs the emulator but i then get "Device not ready. Waiting 3 seconds before next attempt." repeatidly until it says device cannot be found

Comment: I got "Device not ready. Waiting 3 seconds before next attempt" this too

Comment: It helps quite a bit to increase the number of processors for and the priority of the emulator in your task manager.

Answer (score 13):

I faced the same problem. However, it worked after i went to Project->Clean...
Don't know why it happened though.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 10):

I get this problem all the time and have lost many hours of potential productivity and education while I try to fix it.  The only thing that works for me is the combination of three other good answers:

1. Project -> Clean
2. Delete all the AVDs and create new ones
3. If an attempt to run still hangs too long on 'Waiting for HOME' (over two minutes) or the emulator keeps rebooting every minute or so, try  Run as Android App several times, choosing the same existing emulator instance (I always choose runs manually).

It's odd that no one has a clue why this problem comes up, what causes it or what is going on internally.   The only clue I can supply is that DDMS shows a few lines like "Class not found for preloading: libcore.base.CollectionUtils" during the 'Waiting for HOME' pause.

Comment: I dont think you need to Delete all the AVDs and create new ones, just delete the one in question and create a new one

Comment: How 'bout a "Renew AVD" button that, with one click, deletes a selected AVD and recreates it with the same parameters?

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me was to delete the AVD from the AVD manager and create a new one. Then go to
Run >Run Configurations, select the target tab and choose the new AVD.

Answer (score 2):

This problem occurs because while creating the AVD manager in the "Create new Android virtual device(AVD)" dialog window ,"Snapshot" was marked as "Enabled" by me.

### Solution:

Create a new AVD manager with  the "Enabled" checkbox  not checked and then try running the project with the newly created AVD manager as "Target" , the problem will not occur anymore

Comment: I have found this to be the solution that works for me.  I also found that a symptom of the issue was when trying to delete the device while it is *NOT* in use... the AVD would it is unable to delete because it is in use.  New device created --> no problems.

Answer (score 2):

Following steps worked for me:
1. Goto Project -> Clean.
2. Delete your previous AVD and create a new one.

Answer (score 2):

Options:

- Click on the HOME Button on the Emulator. Wait for may be 2
  seconds.... 
     This always works for me!!!

or

- Go with Shreya's suggestion (one with most suggestions and edited by
  Gray).

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue by creating a new virtual device and launching it from the AVD manager. The device takes a few minutes to start, you just have to wait. Then you can run your application on the already started device.

Answer (score 1):

I had only 12 Mb for the SD Card in the AVD device.

Increasing it to 2 Gb solved the issue.

Comment: I had 200 internal and 0 for the sd card. Changing it to 400/200 helped for me.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION:**

Run the emulator from the command line:

```
sdk/tools> ./emulator-x86 -avd <DeviceName> -partition-size 1024 -gpu on
```

Then I launched the app from the command line as well (using built-in Cordova/PhoneGap tools):

```
myapp/cordova> ./run
```

**BACKGROUND**

I believe this is some sort of hardware compatibility issue.  I came across this problem when following the **[PhoneGap 2.4.0 Getting Started Instructions](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.4.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android)**.  I followed their advice to install the Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager, and I think this is the source of my trouble.  Eclipse uses the `emulator64-x86` program (in the `sdk/tools` folder) to launch the emulator.  I could not find any way inside of Eclipse to change this but I found by following the "Tips & Tricks" section of the **[Intel HAXM web page](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-mac-os-x)** that I could get the emulator to run successfully from the command line by using the `emulator-x86` program instead.  I'm not sure why the `emulator64-x86` program doesn't work on my system.  I **[confirmed at the Apple website that I do have a 64-bit processor](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3696)**.

My system:

- OSX 10.6.8
- 2x2.26 GHx Quad-core Intel Xeon
- 6 GB RAM
- ADT v21.1.0-569685
- Eclipse 3.8.0

My AVD:

- Device: Nexus One
- Target: Android 4.2.2 - API Level 17
- CPU: Intel Atom (x86)
- RAM: 512
- Internal Storage: 256
- SD Card: 128

Comment: **UPDATE:** Found confirmation that `emulator64-x86` does not work yet, but that the folks at [Intel are working on a patch](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=37826#c21)

Answer (score 1):

None of these solutions worked for me. Instead, what worked was to go to a command line tool (or terminal in Mac), CD into the SDK/platform-tools directory, and then run this:

```
adb kill-server
```

then run this:

```
adb start-server
```

After I did this everything worked again. Why? Who knows.

On my MAC the path to the platform-tools folder was $HOME/Installations/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130522/sdk/platform-tools
It will probably be somewhere else on your machine.

I also found this page that presents some helpful steps:

http://android.okhelp.cz/android-emulator-wont-run-application-started-from-eclipse/

Answer (score 1):

I created a new device. Deleted the previous one.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was enabling the checkbox "Use Host GPU" when creating or editing the AVD (Android Virtual Device). This checkbox was not enabled by default.

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me when I selected 'Use Host GPU' option under 'Emulation Options:'.

You can find the option under Edit window of the virtual device.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I increased the virtual device SD card size from 500MB to 2GiB, the problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Following steps worked for me: 1. Goto Project -> Clean. 2. Delete your previous AVD and create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this is an old post. However I just ran into the same problem and found a solution. A) Make sure you have the CPU/ABI is atom
B)Ram is 2048
C)VM Heap is 256
D)Internal Storage is 200 
E)Make sure to check the Use Host GPU
F)Device is Nexus 5 (My personal choice)
G)Android 4.4.2 API Level 19