# launch of Android Emulator Failing

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have this problem that many people in Andorid seem to have encountered during their coding . I get the following message when i try to launch my android application on the emulator .

[2012-07-18 02:09:06 - The big expreriment] Failed to install The big expreriment.apk on device 'emulator-5554!

[2012-07-18 02:09:06 - The big expreriment] (null)

[2012-07-18 02:09:06 - The big expreriment] Launch canceled!

It was working like a charm till yesterday . I have thought maybe i made some mistake in my  java file but that does not seem to be the case either . i have added the bare minimum in this file . I have followed a few peoples suggestions like increasing the ADB connection timeout to 10000ms ( it was 5000) , clean building the project , recreating the AVD . Now i dont know what to do . Stuck here for so many hours . Please help someone who has solved this problem .

Comment: When is this occurring? After you've been using the AVD instance for sometime or are you completely unable to run the project on the emulator?

Comment: Well it is coming right away . Completely unable to run the project . Just wont install on the emulator .

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion:

1. run "clean" on your project.
2. Exit Eclipse.  Reboot your PC :)
3. See if it comes back up from a "clean slate".

ALSO:

> http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/optimizing-for-3.0.html
>
> Tip: To improve the startup time for the emulator, enable snapshots
>   for the AVD when you create it with the SDK and AVD Manager (there's a
>   checkbox in the AVD creator to Enable snapshots). Then, start the AVD
>   from the AVD manager and check Launch from snapshot and Save to
>   snapshot. This way, when you close the emulator, a snapshot of the AVD
>   state is saved and used to quickly relaunch the AVD next time.
>   However, when you choose to save a snapshot, the emulator will be slow
>   to close, so you might want to disable Save to snapshot after you've
>   acquired an initial snapshot (after you close the AVD for the first
>   time).

Comment: i am trying out your suggestion . I notice this this step takes along time . [2012-07-18 02:37:31 - The big expreriment] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched... I have observed the same in previous starts as well . I faced the same problem . Peoples answers for the same dont seem to help me . waiting for this to be over ....

Comment: hey this does not solve the problem :( I am at my wits end . phew dont know what next to try ...

Comment: @rockstar: another suggestion: [Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore')](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3073046/waiting-for-home-android-process-acore-to-be-launched): "Wait for few seconds and then right click on the project and click run as Android application once again."

Comment: yes i see that this step speeds up the process i read it in some post . Thanks . However the end result remained the same . I wonder what NULL is . If is a Java exception there must be some logs right ? Is it somehow trying to dereference a NULL value ?

Comment: One more suggestion: create a name *without spaces in it*.  "BigX", for example.

Comment: Ok i am almost on the verge of giving up . I just cam seem to get this error out of my way . This is what
i have tried so far :
a) updated all my software ( eclipse ADT plugin , Android SDK ) 
b) re-created the emulator many times 
c) changed the ADT timeout 
d) changed my workspace as some post suggested that a corrupted workspace can be a potential reason for the problem .
e) included the $SDKHOME/platform-tools and $SDKHOME/tools in the systems environment variables . 

Phew can someone suggest anything ? Can i post this on the site where we can report bugs / issues / request on Android .

Answer (score 0):

try adding a new device to the emulator