# Android Emulator of resolution 1920 X 1080 is not opening

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am doing an `Android App` for the `Accer ics 4.0.1` Tablet. Everything is fine till now.

Till now i tested this app in Android level 4. Now i want to design this app according to the Accer tablet. But to test this I created Android Emulator of resolution 1920 X 1080.

when I trying to run this App Emulator is starting with `Blank screen`. I waited for 20 mins but its showing blank screen only.

In console its showing like this

```
[2012-07-23 08:28:24 - ***] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2012-07-23 08:28:24 - ***] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
```

Any help frineds??

Comment: this issue is discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4968923/696723

Answer (score 0):

just refer this site carefully, before you create your Android Emulator of resolution 1920 X 1080

http://developer.sonymobile.com/knowledge-base/sony-add-on-sdk/install-the-sony-add-on-sdk/#installsdk

http://developer.sonymobile.com/how-to-install-the-sony-add-on-sdk-manually/

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.