# Invalid APK file while loading default app

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, android-virtual-device

I wanted to try to make an Android app, so i downloaded the entire dev pack. Everything seems to work fine, but when i try to launch the app (i haven't modified anything, it just has the default code in it) on my Galaxy S3 with 4.1.1, it tells me that there is an invalid apk file... I tried it on an emulator, it stopped with a black screen and didnt get further than this in the console:

```
[2013-05-01 21:27:06 - MyFirstApp] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
```

Did i do something wrong, or is something missing?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you enable usb debugging from developer options in settings?

Comment: Yes, that is enabled. I also rooted the device, but i dont think that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3073046/waiting-for-home-android-process-acore-to-be-launched) questions answer. Seems similar to your problem. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, creating a new device fixed the device problem, but it still says invalid APK file while trying it on my Galaxy S3...

Comment: Oh well, i tried exporting it and putting it on my device, that works fine. There must be some weird bug... Thanks for the help all.