# Android emulator doesn't launch despite console shows that apk is installed successfully and activity is starting

Tags: android, android-emulator

This question has been asked here multiple times but nothing works for me. I have installed Android SDK on Windows 7 and trying to run HelloWorld project on the emulator. Unfortunately it never launches and just always showing flashing ANDROID label. The console says:

```
Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
```

As [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3073046/waiting-for-home-android-process-acore-to-be-launched) i run my project as Android application once again and yes, things change, now the console happily tells me:

```
[2013-07-27 22:53:36 - HelloWorld] Uploading HelloWorld.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2013-07-27 22:53:37 - HelloWorld] Installing HelloWorld.apk...
[2013-07-27 22:53:55 - HelloWorld] Success!
[2013-07-27 22:53:56 - HelloWorld] Starting activity com.example.helloworld.MainActivity on device emulator-5554
```

but the emulator remains unchanged, just flashing with ANDROID. Can anyone give an advice?

Comment: Is there anything under the LogCat window? It sounds like it may be crashing before it even gets to start. There may be an error message

Comment: there are tons of messages in the LogCat

Comment: You can filter them for just your application by adding a new filter and putting your application in there such as com.myapp.appname that you can find under your manifest.

Comment: there are no messages from my application in the LogCat

Comment: Sometimes there are messages about your manifest that are from the system and not your app. Clear your LogCat and run your app. Look for red or yellow messages

Comment: On DDMS's Devices view, do you see your program running?

Comment: no, i don't. it's clear

Answer (score 1):

Increase ram for the virtual device and try to select a old device with small screen to emulate , btw some times the splash screen may take up to a minute to load depending in your computer

Answer (score 0):

Consiter using this very fast alternative:
[genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/features/)

You can launch from eclipse and android studio, it has great performance.

Comment: i have succesfully installed it according to their guides and Eclipse plugin too, but it's impossible to select the virtual device to launch an app on it